# remote procedure call (RPC) protocol stream is incorrect

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, entity-framework, t-sql

I use entityframework 5.0. I have so many test. If I run a test alone it passes, if I run this with the others eachother in the same time, it does not pass. There is no contact between the tests. Everytime one same query was sent. It would not be modified.

```
**query:**

insert [dbo].[Patient]
       ([AddressId],
        [FirstName],
        [LastName],
        [MiddleName],
        [MuthersName],
        [Sex],
        [BirthDate],
        [TAJNumber],
        [Height],
        [Weight],
        [PhoneMobil],
        [PhoneHome],
        [Email],
        [OtherDisease])
values (13 /* @0 */,
        'Peter' /* @1 */,
        'Peter' /* @2 */,
        'Peter' /* @3 */,
        'Maria' /* @4 */,
        1 /* @5 */,
        '1991-07-04T00:00:00' /* @6 */,
        '5464845' /* @7 */,
        170 /* @8 */,
        66 /* @9 */,
        '00456249864' /* @10 */,
        '00456249864' /* @11 */,
        'alma22@mailmetrash.com' /* @12 */,
        null)



select [Id]
from   [dbo].[Patient]
where  @@ROWCOUNT > 0
       and [Id] = scope_identity()



**WARN:** 
System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException (0x80131904): The incoming tabular data stream (TDS) remote procedure call (RPC) protocol stream is incorrect. Parameter 9 ("@6"): The supplied value is not a valid instance of data type datetime2. Check the source data for invalid values. An example of an invalid value is data of numeric type with scale greater than precision.
   at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection.OnError(SqlException exception, Boolean breakConnection, Action`1 wrapCloseInAction)
   at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlInternalConnection.OnError(SqlException exception, Boolean breakConnection, Action`1 wrapCloseInAction)
   at System.Data.SqlClient.TdsParser.ThrowExceptionAndWarning(TdsParserStateObject stateObj, Boolean callerHasConnectionLock, Boolean asyncClose)
   at System.Data.SqlClient.TdsParser.TryRun(RunBehavior runBehavior, SqlCommand cmdHandler, SqlDataReader dataStream, BulkCopySimpleResultSet bulkCopyHandler, TdsParserStateObject stateObj, Boolean& dataReady)
   at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlDataReader.TryConsumeMetaData()
   at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlDataReader.get_MetaData()
   at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.FinishExecuteReader(SqlDataReader ds, RunBehavior runBehavior, String resetOptionsString)
   at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.RunExecuteReaderTds(CommandBehavior cmdBehavior, RunBehavior runBehavior, Boolean returnStream, Boolean async, Int32 timeout, Task& task, Boolean asyncWrite)
   at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.RunExecuteReader(CommandBehavior cmdBehavior, RunBehavior runBehavior, Boolean returnStream, String method, TaskCompletionSource`1 completion, Int32 timeout, Task& task, Boolean asyncWrite)
   at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.RunExecuteReader(CommandBehavior cmdBehavior, RunBehavior runBehavior, Boolean returnStream, String method)
   at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.ExecuteReader(CommandBehavior behavior, String method)
   at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.ExecuteDbDataReader(CommandBehavior behavior)
   at System.Data.Common.DbCommand.ExecuteReader(CommandBehavior behavior)
   at HibernatingRhinos.Profiler.Appender.ProfiledDataAccess.ProfiledCommand.ExecuteDbDataReader(CommandBehavior behavior)
ClientConnectionId:c184fe10-8d28-4b0b-96bf-395796cd0e29




**exception:**
Test Name:  VM_PatientRegistration_Insert
    Test FullName:  **Insert
    Test Source:    **line 23
    Test Outcome:   Failed
Test Duration:  0:00:01,0018114

Result Message: 
Test method TandoCare.Desktop.Test.ViewModel.PatientRegistrationViewModelTest.VM_PatientRegistration_Insert threw exception: 
System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.DbUpdateException: An error occurred while updating the entries. See the inner exception for details. ---> System.Data.UpdateException: An error occurred while updating the entries. See the inner exception for details. ---> System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException: The incoming tabular data stream (TDS) remote procedure call (RPC) protocol stream is incorrect. Parameter 9 ("@6"): The supplied value is not a valid instance of data type datetime2. Check the source data for invalid values. An example of an invalid value is data of numeric type with scale greater than precision.
Result StackTrace:  
at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection.OnError(SqlException exception, Boolean breakConnection, Action`1 wrapCloseInAction)
   at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlInternalConnection.OnError(SqlException exception, Boolean breakConnection, Action`1 wrapCloseInAction)
   at System.Data.SqlClient.TdsParser.ThrowExceptionAndWarning(TdsParserStateObject stateObj, Boolean callerHasConnectionLock, Boolean asyncClose)
   at System.Data.SqlClient.TdsParser.TryRun(RunBehavior runBehavior, SqlCommand cmdHandler, SqlDataReader dataStream, BulkCopySimpleResultSet bulkCopyHandler, TdsParserStateObject stateObj, Boolean& dataReady)
   at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlDataReader.TryConsumeMetaData()
   at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlDataReader.get_MetaData()
   at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.FinishExecuteReader(SqlDataReader ds, RunBehavior runBehavior, String resetOptionsString)
   at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.RunExecuteReaderTds(CommandBehavior cmdBehavior, RunBehavior runBehavior, Boolean returnStream, Boolean async, Int32 timeout, Task& task, Boolean asyncWrite)
   at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.RunExecuteReader(CommandBehavior cmdBehavior, RunBehavior runBehavior, Boolean returnStream, String method, TaskCompletionSource`1 completion, Int32 timeout, Task& task, Boolean asyncWrite)
   at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.RunExecuteReader(CommandBehavior cmdBehavior, RunBehavior runBehavior, Boolean returnStream, String method)
   at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.ExecuteReader(CommandBehavior behavior, String method)
   at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.ExecuteDbDataReader(CommandBehavior behavior)
   at System.Data.Common.DbCommand.ExecuteReader(CommandBehavior behavior)
   at HibernatingRhinos.Profiler.Appender.ProfiledDataAccess.ProfiledCommand.ExecuteDbDataReader(CommandBehavior behavior)
   at System.Data.Common.DbCommand.ExecuteReader(CommandBehavior behavior)
   at System.Data.Mapping.Update.Internal.DynamicUpdateCommand.Execute(UpdateTranslator translator, EntityConnection connection, Dictionary`2 identifierValues, List`1 generatedValues)
   at System.Data.Mapping.Update.Internal.UpdateTranslator.Update(IEntityStateManager stateManager, IEntityAdapter adapter)
 --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
    at System.Data.Mapping.Update.Internal.UpdateTranslator.Update(IEntityStateManager stateManager, IEntityAdapter adapter)
   at System.Data.EntityClient.EntityAdapter.Update(IEntityStateManager entityCache)
   at System.Data.Objects.ObjectContext.SaveChanges(SaveOptions options)
   at System.Data.Entity.Internal.InternalContext.SaveChanges()
 --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
    at System.Data.Entity.Internal.InternalContext.SaveChanges()
   at System.Data.Entity.Internal.LazyInternalContext.SaveChanges()
   at System.Data.Entity.DbContext.SaveChanges()
   at TandoCare.Infrastructure.Data.UnitOfWork.UnitOfWorkBase`1.Save() in **  at TandoCare.Desktop.Test.ViewModel.PatientRegistrationViewModelTest.VM_PatientRegistration_Insert() in *** :line 55
```

Answer (score 16):

I faced this problem when I tried to insert a new row with a column of `float` data type. The same exception as yours was thrown when I tried to insert `Infinity` or `NaN` values, which are not supported by SQL Server.

if you're using Entity Framework, It's recommended to use the [HibernatingRhinos assembly](http://hibernatingrhinos.com/products/EFProf/learn/). You can trace generated queries and detect the parameter that caused your problem.

SQL Profiler will not help you if your using [TPT (Table-Per-Type)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/cc716702%28v=vs.100%29.aspx).

[image]
[image]

Answer (score 9):

I was issuing a SQLCommand with a select command and I had the error :

> The incoming tabular data stream (TDS) remote procedure call (RPC)
> protocol stream is incorrect. The RPC name is invalid.

Because I was calling a SQLCommand with a command type of `CommandType.StoredProcedure`.

Changing this to `CommandType.Text` fixed my problem.

```
System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand result = new SqlCommand(GetSQLSelectCommande());
        if (FromDate == default(DateTime) || isEqualDay(FromDate, DateTime.Now))
        {
            FromDate.AddMonths(-1);
        }
        ToDate = new DateTime(ToDate.Year, ToDate.Month, ToDate.Day, 23, 59, 59);
        result.Parameters.Clear();
        result.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
        result.Parameters.Add("@IdClient", SqlDbType.Int).Value = this.IdClient;
        result.Parameters.Add("@dateDebut", SqlDbType.DateTime).Value = this.FromDate;
        result.Parameters.Add("@dateFin", SqlDbType.DateTime).Value = this.ToDate;
        result.Parameters.Add("@langue", SqlDbType.Int).Value = (Offix.Culture.GetCulture() == Offix.EnumLangue.ofxFrancais ? 5 : 3);
```

Answer (score 2):

I think the issue is coming from your parameter `@6`. It seems that the format is invalid.
Have you tried some thing like this to create the date? :

```
new DateTime(1991,07,04).ToShortDateString()
```

Comment: I also read that. But if the "parameter" is wrong, Why does it work when I run the test alone? the query is same